# Often, weasel word, and absolutes

Tags: technique

I'm writing about large subjects such as human society, human culture, and human behavior.

I need to identify and discuss various phenomena, and make specific arguments, but I also want to avoid the great trap of absolutes, while also avoiding weasel words.

I discovered that in my efforts to avoid absolutes, I've used the word "often" when introducing types of behaviors and cultural conditions.

I have a great concern for the trap of absolutes.

Any suggestions or ideas about this -- for me -- conundrum?

Comment: Is this academic or more popular writing?

Comment: Believe it or not, I'm attempting to tell a story that will help us connect, help us begin to restore some humanity: Academia is a powerful influence on our culture, with popular press often using the "most cited" as equivalent for the best arguments. So, I'm attempting to attract popular readers of serious non-fiction, as well as any scholars, whether still in the halls, or not, or never.

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be best to make it clear early on that you recognize there are exceptions to almost everything. Make this a sort of rule, state it clearly and significantly, so that you don’t have to be redundant by using “often” or “usually” before every statement you make.

If this doesn’t seem that it will work for you, leave those words in. It’s possible that you use them infrequently enough that readers won’t notice. Perhaps you could get someone to read a section and ask them whether they noticed any word repetition.

Comment: Grace, thanks for sharing your perspective. If I don't continuously make clear that the ideas I'm arguing are not absolutes, then I feel almost certainly that, in today's culture, too many potential minds will evade my arguments and use the slippery attack of my ignorance and believing in absolutes. Your mention of "frequency" is helpful: I might find ways to eliminate some or a few, and still feel that I'm protecting my arguments.

Answer (score 1):

If your goal is to attract scholars, or serious readers of non-fiction, avoid the word "often". It's a word used to brush over something that may not be true, and to, as you noticed, weasel your way out of things.

Specific arguments require specific data. "Often, if a country decides to go to war, few actual people are in agreement about it." Is that really so? Not true for X and Y countries at the start of the Z-war, true for country A for the B-war. List examples of what you are thinking of. Otherwise, you're giving an opinion, rather than no-fiction.

If you want to make generalizations of specific arguments, unless you have more data to back it up, your work might end up being dismissed as either pseudoscience, or pushing an agenda. Cite/mention where you are getting your ideas from, and you will solve the issue you asked about, as well as solidify your arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Don't worry about absolutes, just pay attention to the absolutes you use.

Philosophy deals with absolute universals — it is not about particulars and specifics — so too much qualification or hedging makes the writing look weak and tentative. Say what you mean to say, without giving any sense of embarrassment or hesitation.

That being said, it is up to you to anticipate likely objections and address them as needed. I don't mean that you should identify and discuss exceptions; I mean that you should identify potential exception, paradoxes, or confusions and re-generalize your philosophy so that such are no longer problematic. Philosophy is hermeneutic, and you should use every objection and problem as an opportunity to dig a little deeper and find greater breadth and consistency.